# How to bind updated array values to directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have messages that are coming from server using socket.io, Every time message received i am adding it to `$scope.event` array, How can i update directive isolated scope `message` value when i receive message in controller, its not happening with below code ?

directive.js

```
angular.module("App").directive('progressBarCustom',function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            message: "=",
            fileSize: "=",
        },
        templateUrl: '/view/partials/progressbar.html',
        controller: "StCtrl",
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            var data = scope.message;
    }
});
```

main.html

```
  <ul style="list-style: none;">
                            <li ng-repeat="message in event track by $index" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message}}</span></li>
                        </ul>
```

ctrl.js

```
socket.on('ditConsumer',function (data) {
        $scope.event.push(data);
}

$scope.event = ["lorem ipsum","lorem ipsum"];
```

template.html

```
<progress-bar-custom ng-show="progressBarFlag" message="event"  file-size="selectedFileSize"></progress-bar-custom>
```

Comment: I would `console.log($scope.event)` to make sure it really is updating. It looks like you're doing the two way binding correctly using `'='`

Comment: Is the problem that you're just missing a closing brace on the link function or was that just a transcription error?

Comment: yes its just a transcription error

Answer (score 0):

I never used socket.io but it seems that the callback is being executed outside Angular control, so you should call a $scope.$apply to make Angular aware of the change.

Try this:

```
socket.on('ditConsumer',function (data) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.event.push(data);
  });
}
```

[From documentation:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

$apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.